# Different behaviour between ":last-child" and ":not(:last-child)"

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following html code:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text2</li>
    <li>Text3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Using:

```
nav :last-child {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Result is:

- TEXT1
- TEXT2
- TEXT3

Using:

```
nav li:last-child {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Result is:

- Text1
- Text2
- TEXT3

While using:

```
nav :not(:last-child) {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Result is:

- TEXT1
- TEXT2
- Text3

Why ":not(:last-child)" doesn't need "li" to target the last child?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`nav :last-child` includes your single`<ul>` element. Since there is only one, it is a `:last-child`. So it applies `text-transform: uppercase;` to all if its contents, in this case, all three `<li>` elements.  It is **also** being applied to the last `<li>`, because it is **also** a `:last-child`. To see this more clearly, here is an example with two `<ul>` elements.

```css
nav :last-child {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>This is not a last-child, and parent not a last-child</li>
    <li>This is not a last-child, and parent not a last-child</li>
    <li>Last-child of li in this section</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Parent ul of these li's is a last-child</li>
    <li>So all three li's</li>
    <li>Are uppercase</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

`nav li:last-child` is specific to only `li`'s, so it **only** styles the last `<li>`.

```css
nav li:last-child {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Only applies to li's</li>
    <li>So ul has no style applied</li>
    <li>But this li is a :last-child</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Only applies to li's</li>
    <li>So ul has no style applied</li>
    <li>But this li is a :last-child</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And finally, `nav :not(:last-child)` applies to **anything** that is **:not** a last-child.

```css
nav :not(:last-child) {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>This ul is <b>not</b> a :last-child</li>
    <li>So all of its content</li>
    <li>will be uppercase</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>This ul <b>is</b> a :last-child</li>
    <li>But these first two li's are not</li>
    <li>So they are uppercase</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Better explained than mine :P

Comment: for `:not(:last-child)`, uppercase is applied to the entire first `ul` because it is not a last child. Since the second `ul` is the last child, it didn't apply uppercase to it but it applies to the `li` inside of the second ul since they are not the last child of the parent `ul` and it doesn't apply to the last `li` since it is the last child of the parent `ul`

Comment: "I can see clearly now, the rain is gone". Thanks for your answer, Chris!

Answer (score 0):

`nav :not(:last-child)` basically it means "everthing after nav but not last child". Example below:

```css
nav :not(:last-child) {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text2</li>
    <li>Text3</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Text4</li>
      <li>This one is :not</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I read it again, and your question is: "Why doesn't need "li" to target the last child?" and I explained that it takes everything after nav so, same as doing `nav *`

Comment: it's not *after*, after would mean sibling elements, not child elements

Comment: The last element inside `<nav>...</nav>` will not be targeted..
So even if you have like `<nav><ul><li><ul><li></li><li>This will :not be targeted</li></ul></li></ul></nav>`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the selector `nav :last-child` doesn't select the *last child of any particular `nav` element*, it selects *any descendent* of a `nav` element which is *also the last child among its siblings* (the last child of its parent).

So given the elements

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text2</li>
    <li>Text3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

the css:

```css
nav :last-child {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

will select both the `ul` and the last `li` because they are **both** the last child of their parents.

With the same markup, but with the css

```css
nav :not(:last-child) {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

the `ul` **will not** be selected because it **is** the last child of its parent. However, the first 2 `li` elements will be selected because they are *not* the last child of their parent (among their direct siblings).